# React Native Gradle SDK Location not found. Depreciated Gradle Features

Tags: react-native, gradle, sdk

I am exporting my react native files using : ./gradlew assembleRelease.

I am receiving the following errors:

1. Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0
2. SDK location not found

Is my gradle not compatible with the version of Java I have installed I cannot seem to find how to resolve this?

FULL ERROR BELOW

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_291 (Oracle Corporation 25.291-b10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/mattlaszcz/Documents/HearthNative/HearthNative/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: I can provide the full stack trace if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the sdk path is the in local.properties files in android root folder it should be like that
`sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`

Comment: I cannot see a local.properties file but i have a gradle.properties file would this be the same thing?

Comment: no you can add it to android folder and add this code to it    sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk